# how can i assign types for nearby place using javascript variable

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Edit: Problem solved
I am trying to assign types using variable like this

```
    check = [];

if($("#transport").attr("checked"))
check.push('airport','bus_station','train_station','taxi_stand','travel_agency');

if($("#bars").attr("checked"))
check.push('bar','restaurant');

if($("#tourist").attr("checked"))
check.push('art_gallery','campground','museum','aquarium','zoo','library','amusement_park','park');

if($("#shopping").attr("checked"))
```

check.push('shopping_mall','shoe_store','jewelry_store','grocery_or_supermarket','furniture_store','electronics_store','clothing_store','book_store');

```
 var tmp_types = "";
for(i=0;i<1;i++)
{
    tmp_types += '"'+check[i]+'"';
}

var request = {
    location: latlng,
    radius: '50000',
    types: [ tmp_types ]
  };

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

but its not working... can anybody help me... thanks

solution: just use check in place of tmp_types and remove square brackets..like this types: check.. thanks to Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop exits at 0 because your condition is `i < 1`

```
for( var i=0, len = check.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    // your code here
}
```

Also according to the API documentation the function you are calling expects *types* in the request object to be:

> An array containing one or more of the supported types listed in the
>   Google Places API: Supported Place Types list.

So just use the check object like so

```
var request = {
    location: latlng,
    radius: '50000',
    types: check
};
```

More info [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)

Comment: @anku_radhey Brilliant. That's good. If you could check this as the answer I would be greatful :)